# Redis bitcount command returns a syntax error

Tags: redis, redis-cli

after set myKey as key in Redis with foobar value
I want to get the BITCOUNT of myKey.
this command in Redis-CLI giving me an error:  BITCOUNT myKey 2 3 BYTE

`(error) ERR syntax error`

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BYTE` argument is fairly new and (will be) added in Redis 7.0. So far, only 7.0.0rc3 is released but no GA.

I assume you are using a pre Redis 7 version?

Comment: hi sazzad. thanks for your help. the problem is the version of my Redis. after installing 7.0.0rc3 everything worked well.

Comment: @Mehdi please accept this answer if it was helpful :)